# Preprocessing a image for yolo pretrained net

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, yolo

I am currently working on a project where I need  to use a `yolo3_mobilenet1.0_coco` but the input image needs to be preprocessed from a format`(300,300,3)` to `(1,3,300,300)` which is not being possible by `im.resize((1,3,300,300))`  but  there  are particular functions in `gluoncv` class as `data.transforms.presets.ssd.load_test("string_containing_image_file name", short=512)` but they all take  `"string  of image file name"`  as input argument but I want to pass the variable having the original image as input .

Are there  any function that can allow me to do  that. As it has to be the variable that I  will  be passing as I wont be getting the image file name.

I have  already tried

```
x, img = data.transforms.presets.ssd.load_test(im_fname, short=512)
```

where `im_fname` is the  file name  of the   image  in `(300,300,3)` format .
but I cant pass the file name  as  the images will be going from a `ImageDataGenerator` into a preprocessing func where this yolo net will be  used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `numpy`, you can simply change the image from channel last to channel first using the following code:

```
import numpy as np

img = np.random.randn(300, 300, 3)  # creating random image

print(img.shape) #Out: (300, 300, 3)

img_channel_first = np.moveaxis(img, -1, 0)

print(img_channel_first.shape) #Out: (3, 300, 300)

img_in = img_channel_first[np.newaxis,:]

print(img_in.shape) #Out: (1, 3, 300, 300)
```